# Do different DTO's impact on performance?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a DTO class which has over 40 attributes. Most of the time, i don't use all 40, but 10, 15 tops.

In our JSF project, the user can list all of the records of the database or just a few by selecting some parameters. If the "list all" operation was done with a new DTO class with the 10, 15 attributes which are shown to the user on the screen, i'd gain performance?

Answer (score 0):

The impact of instantiating an Object with some extra null fields, versus querying a DB and serializing your view responses over the network is likely to be miniscule. I would imagine the performance gains here would be negligible. Best bet is to profile your application (using VisualVM or Netbeans profiler for example) - identify which parts of your codebase are the bottleknecks and optimise them.

On the other hand, your code could probably be a lot cleaner / more maintainable if you split up classes with 40+ fields into a series of smaller ones.

**tl;dr** Do it, but for clean code - not performance.